# Add new field on checkout

Tags: php, prestashop

I have created my own module that displays an additional field in the last step on checkout page. I want to validate it when the user press the order button, if the field is empty, I want to return an error.

```
    public function install()
    {
        if (
            !parent::install() ||
            !$this->registerHook('actionBeforeOrderAdd') ||
            !$this->registerHook('displayPaymentTop') ||
            !$this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder') ||
            !$this->registerHook('displayAdditionalCustomerAddressFields') ||
            !$this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder')
        ) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
```

Also:

```
    public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
    {
        $cart = $params['cart'];
        $order = $params['order'];
        $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);
        $extraNumber = Tools::getValue('extra_number');

            if (empty($extraNumber) || strlen($extraNumber) < 3) {
                $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('extra number cannot be empty');
            } else {
                Db::getInstance()->insert('order_additional_number', array(
                    'id_order' => (int) $order->id,
                    'additional_number' => pSQL($extraNumber),
                ));
            }
        
    }
```

Adding custom field via:

```
    public function hookdisplayPaymentTop($params)
{
    $cart = $this->context->cart;

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/customfield.tpl');
}
```

Tpl file:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="extra_number">Extra number</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" id="extra_number" name="extra_number" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

And here there is a problem because the $extraNumber variable is always empty even though the additional field is displayed on the order page.

Ultimately, I want to have an additional field in the last stage of the order and add validation before placing the order so that it will not be possible to place an order if this field is empty.
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Is the `$extraNumber` the additional field are you talking about? Or is it some other field?

Comment: @Adi I've edited question. `$extraNumber` is my custom field.

Comment: So is your code not entering this part
`if (empty($extraNumber) || strlen($extraNumber) < 3) {
                $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('extra number cannot be empty');
            }`

Comment: Also what is $this->l(), is it a typo?